# Trying to make an extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have an extension that i'm trying to add content scrips alongside background scripts but it just says invalid when trying to temp load.

```
{

"description": "Creates tasks and calculates application incomplete date",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Task Creator",
"version": "1.31",

"permissions": [
"http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*",
],

"icons": {
"48": "icons/page-48.png"
},
"web_accessible_resources": [
"style/popUpStyle.css",
"script/popUpTask.js",

"script/logicTaskFiller.js",
"js/autosize.js",
"style/jquery-ui.css",
"js/jquery-1.12.4.js",
"js/jquery-ui.js"
 ],
"content_scripts":{

  "matches": ["*urlhere.com*"],
  "js": ["comSendForm.js"]

},

"background": {
"scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icons/page-32.png"
  }

}
```

I'm not quite sure where i'm messing up. It works instantly after I take out the content scripts, but I'm doing multiple things with this extension and I really do need the content scripts to run on a certain page. Any help is appreciated.

error message 
1477430058898   addons.webextension.   ERROR   Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing content_scripts: Expected array instead of {"matches":["*://*url.com/*"],"js":["comSendForm.js"]}

Comment: What *exactly* is the error you are seeing and where? What, *exactly*, was shown in the [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX) when you tried to install the extension?

Comment: 1477430058898 addons.webextension.<unknown> ERROR Loading extension 'null': Reading manifest: Error processing content_scripts: Expected array instead of {"matches":["*://*url.com/*"],"js":["comSendForm.js"]}

Comment: Well, the first problem is that your *manifest.json* JSON is malformed: `"http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*",` needs to not have the final `,`.

Comment: oh i see where i went wrong. was adding a * to a url. thanks for pointing out the browser console tho, i've been just using f12 to debug didn't realize there was one for the whole browser. was very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you are getting is that your *manifest.json* has the value of the `content_scripts` key as an Object. The value of the [`content_scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/content_scripts) key needs to be an Array of Objects, not just an Object.

In addition, you have the following problems:

- The line:

  ```
  "http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*",
  ```

  should not have the trailing `,`. This is actually reported as the first error, so you may have copied the contents of your *manifest.json* file inaccurately.
- Your `matches` pattern is invalid. You probably wanted something like:

  ```
  "matches": ["*://*.urlhere.com/"],
  ```

With all of those changes your *manifest.json* would look like:

```json
{
    "description": "Creates tasks and calculates application incomplete date",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Task Creator",
    "version": "1.31",
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*", "tabs", "https://*/*"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "48": "icons/page-48.png"
    },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
        "style/popUpStyle.css",
        "script/popUpTask.js",
        "script/logicTaskFiller.js",
        "js/autosize.js",
        "style/jquery-ui.css",
        "js/jquery-1.12.4.js",
        "js/jquery-ui.js"
     ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*://*.urlhere.com/"],
            "js": ["comSendForm.js"]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/page-32.png"
    }
}
```